# ASP.NET Safari and Firefox are not displaying Image from File in <img>-Tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, safari, fileserver

I try to display a list of artikels . 
One Column shows  images.
My Model offers therefore a file-path like this:

> myModel.erstesBild="**\\my-File-server01\Artikel\1-013-538\tn_Klemmscheibe.jpg"**

in my view, I bind the file-path to the src-attribute of an img-tag:

> ```html
>    <tr>
>       <th>Artikelnummer</th>
>       <th>Bilder</th>
>        ...
>        ...    
>    </tr>   
>         @if (Model != null)
>         {  
>           foreach (var item in Model)
>            {
>              <tr>
>                <td>
>                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artikelnummer)
>                </td>
>                <td>
>                  @if (item.erstesBild != null)
>                  {
>                   <a href='@blabla'>
>
>                     <img class="vorschauimg"             
>                          src='@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.erstesBild)' />
>
>                   </a>
>                   }
>                 </td>
>                 ...
>                 ...
>          </tr>
>          }
>         }
>     </table>
> ```

The Internet-Explorer(11) shows the images, 
Firefox(28.0) and Safari(5.1.7) don't.

- Why???

It's an          ASP.NET MVC 5 Application 
created with     VS2013 
hosted on an     IIS-Server (WindowsServer 2008 R2 IIS7)
The File-Server, where the Images are stored, is an WindowsServer 2008 R2 
Clients and servers are in the same domane

What I can get is an access on the files by creating a filestream and checking the "CanRead"-attribute:

```cs
try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(bilder.FirstOrDefault().Quelle);

            using (FileStream sr = fi.OpenRead())
            {
               ViewBag.hatZugriff = sr.CanRead.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.hatZugriff = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Both browsers, Safari an Firefox, retuns **true** for **sr.CanRead**!

- Perhaps it's  because the file-path begins with:
  **src="\\my-data-server01..."** and is not local like **srv="~/.."**?

Comment: It seems so, that I'll have to dive deeper into KERBEROS & CO ....

Comment: .... The IE-Call creates 3 Kerberos-Tickets two with krbtgt/myDomane.com @ myDomane.com an one with the necessary SPN HTTP/myISSserver.myDomane.com . There is also a Tag: ok_as_delegate , for I have tried to place Delegation. The Safari - Call only gets to Kerberos-Tickets.